# Time complexity of recursive function inside for loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

If we have a function:-

```
int x=0;

int fun(int n)
{
    if(n==0) 
        return 1;

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        x += fun(i);
}
```

According to me, time complexity can be calculated as:-

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) +...+ T(0).
T(n) = nT(n-1).

T(n) = O(n!).
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're measuring the number of function calls (or additions -- it turns out the same), the correct recurrence relations are:

```
T(0) = 0
T(n) = T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(n-1) + n
```

You can compute the first few values:

```
 T(0) = 0
 T(1) = 1
 T(2) = 3
 T(3) = 7
 T(4) = 15
```

You can guess from this that T(n) = 2^n - 1, and that's easy to check by a proof by induction.

In some sense you are right that T(n) = O(n!) since n! > 2^n for n>3, but T(n) = O(2^n) is a tighter bound.

Comment: I think if we count the initial function call also then the recurrence would be :- T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) +...+ 1 and not n at the end. For n=3, T(3) = T(0)+T(1)+T(2) + 1 = 1+2+4+1 = 8.

Answer (score 10):

```
1. T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + .... + T(0)

// Replace n with n-1
2. T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) + .... + T(0)
```

Replace `T(n-2) + T(n-3) + .... + T(0)` with `T(n-1)` in 1st Equation

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1)
     = 2 * T(n-1)
     = 2 * 2 * T(n-2) // Using T(n-1) =  2 * T(n-2)
     = 2^n * T(n-n)
     = 2^n * T(0) // Consider T(0) = 1
     = 2^n
```