# Get all exhaustive combinations of 'non-conflicting' lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

Let's say I have a list of lists similar to the one below:

```
lists = [[1,2], [3,4], [4,5], [6,7]]
```

And let's define that two lists 'have no conflicts' if they do not share any one element. So, in the above example, only `[3,4]` and `[4,5]` are conflicting. I can already check if two lists have any conflicts by using:

```
from itertools import combinations

for sets in combinations(lists, 2):
    if not set(sets[0]).isdisjoint(set(sets[1])):
        print(f'the set {sets} has a conflict!')
```

Now I need to get all possible exhaustive combinations of sets of lists that are not conflicting with each other. So for the above example, the combinations would be `[[1,2], [6,7], [3,4]]` and `[[1,2], [6,7], [4,5]]`. How would you recommend to find such combinations no matter how many sets of conflicting lists I have?

Comment: Each of them should be exhaustive? Hence, `[[1,2], [3,4]]` would not be such a combination?

Comment: check `itertools.product`

Comment: @Epsi95 nah, immensely overproducing and then filtering does not seem the right approach.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, the maximum number of non-conflicting elements should be put into a combination. So elements inside a combination cannot form smaller sub-combinations.

Comment: Oh okayy @schwobaseggl

Comment: @Epsi95 In case of `lists=[[1,2], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]` the correct answer would be `[([1, 2], [3, 4], [5,6]), ([1, 2], [4, 5])]`

Comment: why not `[[1,2], [4,5]] , [[3,4],[5,6]`. Just asking

Comment: @Epsi95 Because I should include as many lists into one combination as possible (it should be exhaustive).`[5, 6]` is not conflicting with any of the lists in `[[1,2], [4,5]]` so it should be included.

Comment: okay, sounds reasonable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach that uses dynamic programming:

```
lists = [[1,2], [3,4], [4,5], [6,7]]
tups = [tuple(lst) for lst in lists]#tuples needed for set operations

def validate_combo(list_of_lists):
    '''helper function to validate a combo'''
    flattened = [num for lst in list_of_lists for num in lst]
    return len(flattened) == len(set(flattened))

DP = [[item] for item in tups] #dynamic programming table
for i in range(len(tups)):
    for j in range(len(tups)):
        temp = list(DP[i])
        temp.append(lists[j])
        if validate_combo(temp):
            DP[i].append(tups[j])
            
#elimiate duplicates
result = []
for lst in DP:
    if set(lst) not in result:
        result.append(set(lst))

print(result)

#[{(6, 7), (1, 2), (3, 4)}, {(6, 7), (4, 5), (1, 2)}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I checked the execution time of both your and @Ajax1234's answers using `timeit` and yours is indeed considerably faster. I deal with big inputs so time complexity is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def combos(d, c = []):
   if c and sum(map(len, c)) == len({i for b in c for i in b}):
      yield sorted(c)
   for i in d:
      yield from combos(d[1:], c+[i])
   
def get_results(d):
   k = sorted(combos(d), key=len)
   return [a for i, a in enumerate(k) if all(not all(l in j for l in a) for j in k[i+1:])]

for i in [[[1,2], [3,4], [4,5], [6,7]], [[1,2], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]]:
   print(get_results(i))
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 7]], [[1, 2], [4, 5], [6, 7]]]
[[[1, 2], [4, 5]], [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]]
```

Comment: Beautiful. What’s the Big O Of your recursive function? I’m trying to compare it to my DP solution.

Comment: @pakpe A tight approximate time complexity is `O(2^n)`, due to the fact that at each iteration over `d`, a slice of `d` is passed to the recursive call of `combos`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768127/time-complexity-of-recursive-function-inside-for-loop) provides the recurrence relation for that complexity result. More broadly, however, the upper bound for this type of iterative-recursive pattern is `O(n!)`.

Comment: That’s what I thought. The dynamic solution is O(n^2). The recursive solution is very elegant though.

Comment: @pakpe Thank you, your solution is a very clever implementation of dynamic programming!